# Android Fonts downloadable, how I change from regular to semibold

Tags: android, android-fonts

I'm working in a project which uses downloadable fonts from google, however it font is by default **regular**.

How could I change it to **SemiBold** ??

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the font to semi-bold but you can use a library for fonts like this one [Click here](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/7519)